Convergence of integrals wrt empirical distribution
I have iid samples $X_1, \dots, X_n$ from some distribution $\mathcal{P}$. Based on them I can construct an empirical distribution $\mathcal{P}_n$, where
$$\mathcal{P}_n (A) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i = 0}\mathbb{1}_{X_i \in A} $$
I can integrate over this distribution $\int f d \mathcal{P}_n$. I want to find any results on the convergence of these integrals to the integral wrt to the REAL distribution $\mathcal{P}$:
$$\int_\Omega f d \mathcal{P}_n \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_\Omega f d \mathcal{P}$$

That's just the strong law of large numbers.

@MichaelGreinecker, you mean that LHS is $\sum f(X_i)$ and it converges to expected value of $f$ (which is RHS)?

Yes, though you also need $n^{-1}$ on the LHS.

Yes, forgot to write it down. @MichaelGreinecker, originally I wanted to as a question about integral of $f(F_n(X_{i_0})) dP$, where $F_n$ is an empirical distribution function. So I wanted to integrate function of EDF at a random variable $X_{i_0}$. In the light of your comments, can I say that $\int f(F_n(X_{i_0})) d\mathbb{P} = \int f(u) d P_n \to \int f(x) dx$?

I don't think $ f(F_n(X_{i_0}))$ is good notation.

@MichaelGreinecker, I wanted to say that I built EDF $F_n$ from $n$ samples $X_1, \dots, X_n$, then calculated $F_n(X_{i_0})$, which means, that I calculated just a function of $X_{i_0}$ (which gave me discrete rv) and then applied some other function $f$ to the later rv. And I wanted to calculate it's expectation. Then I wanted to use your argument to say that this expectation will converge to expectation of $f(U)$, where $U \sim Uniform(0, 1)$.

I get the point, I just don't think the notation is good. There is a huge literature on empirical processes that you can look at.

@MichaelGreinecker, could you please recommend the most relevant one?

The area gets very technical very fast, but the first part of this might be relevant: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~geer/empirical-processes.pdf

thank you, @MichaelGreinecker!
